# Laplace transform.

Tags: laplace-transform

This is a past exam question.  I'm having a bit of trouble at finding the inverse laplace transform of the following function.  Any help would be great.  $$\frac{s^2+1}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}$$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From the standard Laplace transforms
$$L(\sin at)=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  L(\cos at)=\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}$$
and the general rule
$$L(tf(t))=-\frac{d}{ds}L(f(t))$$
we obtain
$$L(t\sin at)=\frac{2as}{(s^2+a^2)^2}$$
and a similar rule for $L(t\cos at)$.  Your function can be written
$$\eqalign{\frac{s^2+1}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}
  &=\frac{(s^2+4s+5)-(4s+4)}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}\cr
  &=\frac{1}{s^2+4s+5}-\frac{4s+4}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}\cr
  &=\frac{1}{(s+2)^2+1}-\frac{4(s+2)}{((s+2)^2+1)^2}+\frac{4}{((s+2)^2+1)^2}
    \ ,\cr}$$
and the result follows from the above and shifting on the $s$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{s^2+1}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}=\dfrac{s^2+4s+5-4s-4}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}=$$

$$\dfrac{1}{s^2+4s+5}-\dfrac{4s+4}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}=(\text{1st part is easy})$$

$\dfrac{1}{s^2+4s+5}=\dfrac{1}{(s+2)^2+1^2}=e^{-2t}sin(t)$

Comment: The last equal sign should be replaced by another sign. I personnaly like this one $\sqsubset$.